# How to Move image file from gallery to another folder

Tags: java, android

I want to get Image from gallery and save it to another folder. I tried with code

```
private void copyFile(File inputPath, File outputPath){
        try{

                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    in = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    in = null;

                    // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    out = null;

                    Log.d("Copied file to ", outputPath.toString());

                } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
                    Log.d("Tag",fnfe1.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("tag", e.getMessage());
                }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you use java 8 or higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using try-with-resources and the java 8 Files / Path api:

```
private void copyFile(File inputPath, File outputPath){
 try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)) {

     Files.copy(inputPath.toPath(), fos);
     Log.d("Copied file to ", outputPath.toString());

  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
     Log.d("Tag",fnfe1.getMessage());
  } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.d("tag", e.getMessage());
  }
}
```